# Document Content Types into Custom List

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-type, custom-list

I am sure this is the way but don't know why it's acting funny.  Created a custom list.  The idea is to be able to upload documents into the custom list library.  If I create a custom list and add a file content type, wouldn't this work?  The problem is that I cannot find a file content type or any document content type except document set.

Am I wrong by using a content type?  Am I looking at the wrong content types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a list with all of the information you need and also have a document library for the documents. 
In the document library have a column that is a lookup to the Sharepoint List so that you can relate the documents to the list item (or to multiple items if you use a multi picker).
The benefit of using this method over Eric Alexander's is that you can access the documents in the library via Window Explorer. On the downside this method has a two stage approach rather than just adding a list item with its attached document.

In the list item you could also have a 'List Webpart' that shows the related documents to that particular item (filtered by the list item's ID).

Answer (score 7):

That isn't the way SharePoint works. Lists and libraries are the 2 basic storage mechanisms for things. You either create an entry (list) or upload a file (library).

If you want to upload files to a list, it has to be as an attachment to a list item. You can't upload a file to a list in any other way. Otherwise, you need to upload the file to a document library that has the custom metadata you need.

Answer (score 0):

Appears 'site pages' is now another storage mechanism that can't be integrated into documents.

Splitting out content by format is not how libraries should work to the end user's benefit. It would be like splitting a physical library of books about into hard-back books, soft-back books, and books that contain an optical disk in them; people trying to find all the books about Sharepoint would have to (a) know to look in three places and (b) go to each shelf separately to discover what is there.

Having a single place for content about a subject is hugely beneficial, means people only have one place to go to find or add the information.

I know there are convoluted workarounds to this - highlighted content can bring a list, site pages, and document library together into one (though users can't then filter that content unless we install a custom search webpart into the tenant). And you could have links at the top of the page to 'Add a page | Add a document | Add an external resource', however from an admin and end users perspective it's all very unintuitive.