# Can we add the document as well as item (like list item) to the list or document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have to add the documents as well as items in the list or document library.
Here is the either or option like- Admin can add the document or link(item like list)
Is it possible with the content type or any other approach to do that?

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brief**: Document Libraries and List are two different things. Both holds different content type. If you Allow Management of Content Types via List Settings > Advanced Settings, you will observe the content type that are available for document library are not available for a List like Custom List and vice-versa.

**Solution**: But to address your requirement you can have **documents** and **link to documents** Content type in the same document library. Allow Management of Content Types to `YES` via Library Settings > Advanced Settings. Then `Add from existing content types` select - **Link to Document**.

I hope this solution addresses your requirement as what you have asked in question - "Admin can add the document or link(item like list)"

You can also check this post [Document Content Types into Custom List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167259/document-column-types-into-custom-list). In this post Eric also confirmed the same thing.

Comment: Hello Zakir,
Thanks for your valuable solution.
It's worked fine.